# 2 routers connected in series and port forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat

I have 2 routers connected in series. 
On one of them I can't have access because it's my ISP's router and that's their policy. 
To their router I have connected an Asus router (AC56U) to which I connect with my windows computer.

I also have a server which runs on my local computer with the address `192.168.1.252:7000`

What I need is to port forward this in order to be able to connect to my server publicly.
I tried to make a port forwarding in my Asus router, but it doesn't work, and I suspect it has something to do with the ISP's router.

What are the solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are able to get into the router of your ISP or replace it by a different router, there are no options.

The traffic goes as follows: `Internet` > `ISP router` > `Your router` > `Your server`.

In order for a package to be able to fully reach your server, the ports have to be forwarded on both the ISP Router and Your router.

It may be possible to ask your ISP to set the router in bridged mode. It will assume a router is attached to the modem/router and it will forward all ports automatically to the first LAN port.

EDIT: There is one more thing you can try. Google for your ISP's name, plus router password. They often set a standard password to all their devices, and may have told someone in the past who put it on the internet.

Comment: And other than port forwarding, what other options are still available?

Comment: Considering you're behind a NAT/Firewall, there's no other option! Your ISP's router drops packets before they reach yours. To be clear, the only packets that can get into your network, are the ones returning in answer of a session you initiated! What kind of policy is this? Are you a customer, or a prisoner?? Just ask them to setup the port forwarding for you, or pack their things and leave your home! You are paying for service, and they are refusing to do so. If it's not explicitly defined in your EULA, so they are preventing your rights.

Comment: See my answer. Replace the router or put in bridged mode. You will somehow need to tell the package what route it must take, which requires port forwarding of some sort. Setting a router in bridged mode, essentially creates a rule that puts all ports to LAN port 1. Another option is switching ISP of course.

Comment: @AmirHossein there are ISP's that do this deliberately to prevent you from setting up a server, because a server means a higher bandwidth usage, and they do not restrict bandwidth. Usually this is against torrenting though...

Comment: @LPChip I know, I hate these kind of contracts. I feel chained up if I can't configure my router. LOL

Comment: @AmirHossein, the reason residential Internet is so cheap is that you have a lot of restrictions. If you want unfettered Internet access, get a business account, but expect to pay several times more for less speed.

Comment: They are the only ISP in this zone and I've asked them once to give me their access password, but they've told me that only their "specialists" are authorized to do anything. I've also asked them to switch their router with mine, but they rejected my proposition, because "that's our policy". I haven't asked them about putting the router in bridged mode though ..

Comment: Have you tried replacing your isp router with yours? If you do it can take up to 24 hours for the new router to get a new dhcp lease before you have internet connectivity.

Comment: @Moab His ISP Router will be a modem/router combination. Without access to the configuration he likely can't figure out how to setup the modem part, let alone if his router has the MODEM connections required.