# How to SSH to computer with both public and private IPs using DDNS

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ssh, ip

I have a Mac laptop (computer A) running OS X el capitan that I would like to remotely access with SSH. Since the computer is always on my school network, I cannot get a static, public IP address. After doing research, I've learned that I can

1. set mac os x to request a certain private IP on my school network
2. use ddclient to always update the public IP my computer has to nsupdate.info such that a static url always points to computer A

As mentioned before, computer A is on my school network. How can I use my computer (computer B) on my home network, which is far from my school, to ssh into computer A?

Let's say I have set computer A to configure IPv4 using DHCP with manual IP address 172.27.133.200 and to use ddclient to update testurl.nsupdate.info to always point to the public IP address of computer A. Is there a command that would use these two addresses such that I can connect, e.g. (conceptually)

`userOnComputerB$ ssh userOnComputerA@172.27.133.200@testurl.nsupdate.info`

I also welcome other solutions that work within the confines of the problem. I have consulted other [questions involving reverse tunneling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87432/ssh-to-private-ip) and [port forwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/1112591/how-to-ssh-to-a-private-ip-behind-a-router-using-public-dynamic-ip), but don't see how they apply to this, because I think I do not have any control over the port forwarding of my school network routers.

Lastly, if a command like the one above is not possible, what is the technical or ssh design reason why such a command is not possible?

Comment: Your credentials have to be granted access from the school's Network Administrator. Start there, they are the only one who can allow you access to the network remotely.

Comment: In the reverse tunnel question that you refer to, consider lappy to be your school computer and remotey to be your home computer. Does that not achieve what you want?

Answer (score 0):

When you SSH to testurl.nsupdate.info the connection will terminate at your school's firewall (or other device which implements NAT for your internal IP 172.27.133.200). The firewall will not know that this needs to be forwarded to your internal IP, unless the firewall admin had configured port forwarding but as you say, you have no control over that.

If you think of it, the firewall's mean reason for existence is exactly to prevent someone on the outside to be able to connect to a device on the inside (except those connections that the firewall admin approved).

However, typically the firewall *does* allow your internal device to SSH to the outside, so then you could use that outbound SSH connection to tunnel an inbound connection, which is explained in [questions involving reverse tunneling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87432/ssh-to-private-ip) that you mentioned. Just read this while keeping in mind that "lappy" is your school computer and "remotey" your home computer.

Comment: In the linked example, the author says that `lappy` and `remotey` are on the same network, and `remotey` is used as an intermediate point between `lappy` and another computer (which the OP refers to as computer C). Does this mean that it is necessary to use 3 computers, where `lappy` and `remotey` are on the same network, and computer C is on my home network?

Comment: I could do that, but as the author writes, that requires two steps: first login to `remotey` then use the reverse tunnel port. I would like data to be end-to-end encrypted between the home computer and `lappy`. Would that be the case if I logged-in to `remotey` as an intermediate? Is there one single command I could use to merge these two steps?

Comment: ok sorry if that was confusing. Ignore the question in the linked example, focus on the first part of the answer that just talks about lappy and remotey. This part is where you should have a working connection from remotey (home pc) to lappy (school pc): `test out reverse tunnel port
[user@remotey ~]$ ssh -p 12345 localhost
should now be back on lappy
user@localhost's password: 
Last login: Thu Aug  1 17:53:54 2013
/usr/bin/xauth:  creating new authority file /home/user/.Xauthority
[user@lappy ~]$ `

Comment: Ok, thanks. However the author of the answer is able to do that login because `lappy` and `remotey` are on the same network. In my case neither my school computer nor my home computer have static public IPs. Does that mean the intermediate computer is necessary? Could I use one login for end-to-end encryption?

Comment: Ok I didn't realize that your home computer does not have a public IP. In that case I think you have 2 options: indeed use a third computer "C" that has a public IP. Or configure DDNS on your home PC and from the school PC set up the SSH tunnel towards "myhomepc.nsupdate.info". Configure your home router to do port forwarding to your home PC.
Downside is that you will need to somehow restart the tunnel when your public IP at home changes; I suppose you could write some cron job that tests if the ip has changed and then re-established the connection.